# Setting the name of an object in Powerpoint as a String

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a powerpoint slide with about 3000 slides. On each slide I have a one picture and a text box. In powerpoint the picture has a specific name attached to it in the selection pane while the text box is named "TextBox 3". Each text box contains the text "2013-09-27 16.27.54". My job is to go through each text box and replace that text with name of the picture in the selection pane. I have written the following code to do this however I am having trouble setting the name of the picture as a string. When I run this code I get "Compile error: Invalid qualifier" on line 10, and Name is highlighted in line 10

How do I get rid of this error? I am assuming it is because the name of the object is not being recognized as a string.

My code is as follows:

```
Sub Hello()


For Each sld In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.HasTextFrame Then
            Set txtRng = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
            Set foundText = txtRng.Find(FindWhat:="2013-09-27 16.27.54")
            Do While Not (foundText Is Nothing)
                With foundText
                .Replace(FindWhat:=foundText, _
          Replacewhat:=Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(1).Name.TextRange.TextFrame, WholeWords:=True) = True
            
             
                End With
            Loop
        End If
End If
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The object name **is a string**... Do you receive an error? If yes, what error and on which line? If not, what "my code will not work" does mean? Your code uses `shp.TextFrame` in a loop where `shp.HasTextFrame = False`...

Comment: Telling us about line 12, after you removed something from the code, is not so clear... Try copying here the code line in discussion. But your code misses an important issue: Since there are text boxes and pictures, both of them being shapes, you must firstly identify what type is the shape to be processed. Then `Set NameofPicture = shp.Name` is wrong, since the 'Name` property is not an object. I would suggest you to use `Option Explicit` on top of your module, declare all involved variables and try running and debugging only after that. And exclude iteration between all slides on debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Find and Replace is unnecessarily complex. Find the picture, get its name, find the text box, replace the text:

```
Sub Hello()
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim PicName As String

    For Each sld In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.Type = msoPicture Then
                PicName = shp.Name
            End If
        Next
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.HasTextFrame Then
                shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = PicName
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```